# Anime: people are on a space ship that never lands, something aboard the ship that's very dark, old enough to have been on VHS

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember this anime vaguely but it made me feel quite creeped out, I don't think it had multiple parts but it certainly could have.

Possibly people were cryogenically asleep or something? I seem to recall maybe a black goo involved with the antagonist but maybe not.

It's not the episode of *Cowboy Bebop* with the rotten sandwich, it was 100% dark, little humor if any, and they didn't land at all - very isolated.

Answer (score 7):

Not much to go on. Could it be [Lily C.A.T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lily_C.A.T.)?

> Lily C.A.T. is a science fiction anime film released in 1987. Carl Macek, best known for producing and story editing Robotech, produced the English version of the film. Famous Japanese artists and illustrator Yoshitaka Amano is co-credited for character design, and monster design as he created the gruesome forms of the alien.
>   Visually and thematically, the film has many aspects in common with the American science-fiction/horror films Alien and The Thing.

Comment: ^ YES thank you that really is it

Comment: @coob market as correct please.